# Probleme PHP DATE showing 1970

Tags: php, date, time

if I converter my date to french format he showing me **jeudi 01 janvier 1970**

```
  $DeliveryDate = $v->EstimatedDeliveryDateMin;// 16/08/2013
  $PrevDate = strftime('%A  %d  %B  %Y', strtotime($DeliveryDate));

  echo $PrevDate
```

He show jeudi 01 janvier 1970

Please Helpe me;

Comment: `%A  %d  %B  %Y` **doesn't** look like `16/08/2013`

Comment: What should I do ? please can u helpe me

Comment: Find your answer from w3schools http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_strftime.asp i think strtotime not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$DeliveryDate = $v->EstimatedDeliveryDateMin;// 16/08/2013
$DeliveryDate = str_replace('/', '-', $DeliveryDate);
$PrevDate = strftime('%A  %d  %B  %Y', strtotime($DeliveryDate));
echo $PrevDate ;
```

Add extra line, strtotime doesn't work for the format "16/08/2013" but "16-08-2013"

Answer (score 0):

Use "-" instead of "/"

```
$DeliveryDate = '16-08-2013';
$PrevDate = strftime('%d/%m/%Y', strtotime($DeliveryDate));
echo $PrevDate;
```

You can use str_replace function, so:

```
$DeliveryDate = str_replace('/', '-', $v->EstimatedDeliveryDateMin)
$PrevDate = strftime('%A  %d  %B  %Y', strtotime($DeliveryDate));
echo $PrevDate
```

Comment: Your exemple show 01/01/1970 or I like to converter to french format jeudi 14 Aout 2013

Comment: I tried my code before posting it and works fine. Are you sure that $v->EstimatedDeliveryDateMin is returning 16/08/2013?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`DateTime` object](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) instead:

```
$deliveryDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $v->EstimatedDeliveryDateMin);
$prevDate = $deliveryDate->format('l d F Y');

echo $prevDate;
```

[Here’s a demo!](http://codepad.viper-7.com/28cj5h)